# Logical error displaying randomized array

Tags: java, arrays

so im pretty new to the whole JAVA gang and im just working on a project for my class. Im finished with all the backbone work but for the past 3 days ive been stuck on this issue.

So, lets say i have an array of, 
1a, 2b, 3c, 4d. and i wish to randomize it buy changing the indexes (already done). but when i print the array out, it comes up as a variant of this.

1a, 1a, 4d, 3c. (yet again this is randomized but the point is the first object thats printed is always duplicated but in reality there are no duplicates in the array, just the displaying method.)

this is the code i have for this program. Consists of 3 classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Deck
{
public static void main(String [] args) 
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    DeckOfCards d = new DeckOfCards();
    int in;
    d.createNewDeck();
    System.out.println("Shuffling Deck...");
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the deck. Enter 2 to view the array in its current form. Enter 3 to force shuffle the array. 9 to exit");
        in = s.nextInt();

        if (in == 0) {
            System.out.println(d.deal());
        } else if (in == 1) {
            System.out.println(d.cardsLeft());
        } else if (in == 2) {
            System.out.println(d.toString());
        } else if (in == 3) {
            d.shuffle();
        }
    } while (in != 9);
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;
public class DeckOfCards
{
public Random r = new Random();
public Card [] deck;
public int current;
public int temp;
public int index;
public DeckOfCards() {
    deck = new Card[52];
    current = 0;
    createNewDeck();
}
public void createNewDeck() {
    deck[0] = new Card("A","C");
    deck[1] = new Card("2","C");
    deck[2] = new Card("3","C");
    deck[3] = new Card("4","C");
    deck[4] = new Card("5","C");
    deck[5] = new Card("6","C");
    deck[6] = new Card("7","C");
    deck[7] = new Card("8","C");
    deck[8] = new Card("9","C");
    deck[9] = new Card("10","C");
    deck[10] = new Card("J","C");
    deck[11] = new Card("Q","C");
    deck[12] = new Card("K","C");
    deck[13] = new Card("A","D");
    deck[14] = new Card("2","D");
    deck[15] = new Card("3","D");
    deck[16] = new Card("4","D");
    deck[17] = new Card("5","D");
    deck[18] = new Card("6","D");
    deck[19] = new Card("7","D");
    deck[20] = new Card("8","D");
    deck[21] = new Card("9","D");
    deck[22] = new Card("10","D");
    deck[23] = new Card("J","D");
    deck[24] = new Card("Q","D");
    deck[25] = new Card("K","D");
    deck[26] = new Card("A","S");
    deck[27] = new Card("2","S");
    deck[28] = new Card("3","S");
    deck[29] = new Card("4","S");
    deck[30] = new Card("5","S");
    deck[31] = new Card("6","S");
    deck[32] = new Card("7","S");
    deck[33] = new Card("8","S");
    deck[34] = new Card("9","S");
    deck[35] = new Card("10","S");
    deck[36] = new Card("J","S");
    deck[37] = new Card("Q","S");
    deck[38] = new Card("K","S");
    deck[39] = new Card("A","H");
    deck[40] = new Card("2","H");
    deck[41] = new Card("3","H");
    deck[42] = new Card("4","H");
    deck[43] = new Card("5","H");
    deck[44] = new Card("6","H");
    deck[45] = new Card("7","H");
    deck[46] = new Card("8","H");
    deck[47] = new Card("9","H");
    deck[48] = new Card("10","H");
    deck[49] = new Card("J","H");
    deck[50] = new Card("Q","H");
    deck[51] = new Card("K","H");
    current = 0;
}
public void shuffle() {
    for (int i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        deck[temp] = deck[index];
        deck[index] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[temp];
    }
    current = 0;
}
public Card deal() {
    current++;
    return deck[current-1];
}
public int cardsLeft() {
    return deck.length - current;
}
public String getCurrentSuit() {
    return deck[current].getSuit();
}
public String getCurrent() {
    return deck[current].toString();
}
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        s = s + deck[i] + " ";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Card
{
private String suit;
private String face;

public Card() {
    suit = "S";
    face = "A";
}
public Card(String f, String s) {
    face = f;
    suit = s;
}
public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}
public String toString() {
    return face + suit;
}
}
```

---

A bit of explanation for the code is that the `DeckOfCards` class is the array along with the methods used to "shuffle" and "deal" the card. The array stores 52 objects of the "Card" class and the main driver is the "Deck" class.

### Here is one of the tests i did to show the issue in action,

Shuffling Deck...

Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the 
deck. 9 to exit

1
52

Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the deck. 9 to exit

2

AC 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C 10C JC QC KC AD 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D 10D JD QD KD AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S 10S JS QS KS AH 2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 8H 9H 10H JH QH KH

Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the deck. 9 to exit

3

Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the deck. 9 to exit

2

**JC JC** KH AH 5S 2C 3S 6S JS JD KC 4S 9H 10H 6D 9D 7C 5H QD 4D 2H 8C 10C 7H 10S 9S AS KS 6C 7D 5D QH 3H 8D 3D 2S 4H 6H 2D QS 8S JH 4C 9C KD 8H QC 10D 5C 3C AD 7S

Enter 0 to deal a card. Enter 1 to get the ammount of remaining cards in the deck. 9 to exit

---

Thanks a million to anyone who can help!

Comment: To shuffle an array, all you need is `Arrays.asList(array).shuffle()`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there are standard libraries to shuffle.

Your shuffle has a defect; you use the deck array as a means of storing a temporary value.  You probably meant to do this:

```
public void shuffle() {
    for (int i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        index = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        Card temp = deck[index];
        deck[index] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = temp;
    }
    current = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After doing more stressing, i realized i was using TEMP but it was never initialized and was doing some weird things which made it = to 0. After realizing that, i came back to look here and see you have blessed me with a solution. Thank you so much!